# How to randomly select N-node subtree of arbitrary tree

Tags: algorithm, tree, probability, combinatorics

I have a giant data set in a tree structure. I'm trying to write a function that takes in that tree and a number N, and outputs a random tree of size N that contains the root of the larger tree and is contained by the larger tree, such that all such possible subtrees are (at least roughly) equally likely to be returned. The average node of the larger tree has dozens of children, and the function should ideally not take forever when N=1000. Is that possible?

[This paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2102.12738.pdf) looks like it has exactly that in section 8.2, but I don't understand a single word.

I have no ideas. I tried to look up the existing literature and apparently found the answer, but if it's in there I don't understand it, and I certainly don't know how to turn the solution into working code. Every obvious algorithm either doesn't select uniformly or requires comically large amounts of memory and running time.

Comment: I could write up an implementation of that algorithm when I get a chance, but I don't think it's what you want. The first problem is that it samples uniform subtrees of *any* size, which leaves you having to run the chain until it spits out one of size N (which, if that size is rare, may take a comically large amount of time, as you say). The second problem is that, in general, it may not mix all that fast in the first place – probably Omega(m^2) time in the worst case where m is the number of nodes in the original tree. I think the direct algorithms are probably your best bet.

Comment: The direct algorithm would be (I think) O(m N log N) time and O(m N) memory, with the possibility of reducing memory usage at the expense of added time.

Comment: The algorithm that I can think of will require creating a data structure with `O(m N)` entries. where `m` is the size of the big tree, and `N` is the size of the tree you want. Each entry will be a big integer counting subtrees.  This will take a lot of memory. You can just store the `log` of each number, though. Generating trees is then something like `O(N^2 b)` where `b` is the branching factor. Is this acceptable?

Comment: Probably some kind of approximation is going to be best.  Can you explain *why* you want a uniform choice over all possible subtrees?

Answer (score 0):

Sampling random subtrees via coupling from the past, as promised.

```py
import collections
import itertools
import random


# A tree is represented by a list mapping each node to its parent.
test_tree = [None, 0, 0, 2, 3, 3]


class AddNode:
    def __init__(self, u):
        self._u = u

    def __call__(self, tree, nodes):
        if tree[self._u] in nodes:
            nodes.add(self._u)


class DiscardNode:
    def __init__(self, u):
        self._u = u

    def __call__(self, tree, nodes):
        if all(tree[v] != self._u for v in nodes):
            nodes.discard(self._u)


# Coupling from the past.
def sample_subtree(tree):
    n = len(tree)
    T = 1
    steps = []
    while True:
        for t in range(T):
            steps.append(random.choice([AddNode, DiscardNode])(random.randrange(1, n)))
        upper = set(range(n))
        lower = {0}
        for step in reversed(steps):
            step(tree, upper)
            step(tree, lower)
        if upper == lower:
            return upper
        T *= 2


def is_subtree(tree, nodes):
    return all(node == 0 or tree[node] in nodes for node in nodes)


def test():
    n = len(test_tree)
    counter = collections.Counter()
    for i in range(100000):
        counter[frozenset(sample_subtree(test_tree))] += 1
    print(min(counter.values()) / max(counter.values()))
    assert all(is_subtree(test_tree, sub) for sub in counter)
    for k in range(1, n + 1):
        for comb in itertools.combinations(range(1, n), k):
            nodes = frozenset((0,) + comb)
            assert not is_subtree(test_tree, nodes) or nodes in counter


test()
```